# Check if name exists in database (firstname lastname)

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a database with a table that contains names, some examples in the column of name:

- "John Doe"
- "Kevin De Bruyne"

So you'll notice that a name contains multiple words.

I also got a spreadsheet with a list of names, this is there structure:

- "DOE John"
- "DE BRUYNE Kevin"

**(last names in caps and in front of first name)**

My question is how i can write a query that checks if the name in my spreadsheet is already in the database.

I tried it with some basic queries but i couldn't figure it out so i think i'll need regular expressions to split the words? How can I do this?

This is what i have to split the words, how can i build the query? Thank you!

```
(\b[^\s]+\b) (splits "My name is Onovar" into "My","name","is" and "Onovar")
```

***Database structure:**

- Database name: mydb
- table: people
- column: name

*So i need something like: If 'name from spreadsheet' does not exist in table people, insert 'name of spreadsheat' into table people**

Comment: you don't need regexp for this functionality, use explode(" ") instead, then you can itterate over that array instead.

Comment: @PhilipG How do I use explode in a MySql Query to compare the names? (first and last names should be the same of course.)

Comment: That depends on how your mysql table looks like. Could you uodate with your database structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found it.

So i put my data from my excel in an array.

```
$array = ["name1 firstname1","name2 firstname2",...];
```

i go trough every element, split the words (space)

```
foreach ($array as $element){
        $subex =  explode(' ', $element);
```

then I copy the last element to the front

```
array_unshift($subex , end($subex));
```

and delete the last part so i have this array: "firstname,name"

```
array_pop($subex);
```

next, i break the array so i get a string like this: "firstname name"

```
$naam = implode(' ', $subex);
```

after that i make everything lowercase

```
$low = strtolower($naam);
```

except the first letters of each words, they have to be caps

```
$up = ucwords($low);
```

after that i create my myqsl query that skips doubles and adds new ones

```
echo 'INSERT IGNORE INTO politici
    SET naam = "'.$up.'",
    partij_id = 23;';
    echo '<br />';

}
```

And i had to be sure that every name column is unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
$array = explode(" ", $string);
$names = implode(",", $array);
$query = "SELECT * FROM persons WHERE id IN ($names)";
```

then you run the query using PDO or mysqli.

**EDIT**

missread the question. Above solution uses php
What you realy need is all names in a comma seperated list, then you could use this query

```
"SELECT * FROM persons WHERE id IN ($names)"
```

where $name would be your comma separated list.

Comment: In this case (Edit part of the answer), It only checks if the string is exactly the same. So when i use it like this: "SELECT * FROM persons WHERE id IN ("Kevin De Bruyne", "DOE John")"; It will only find Kevin and not John.

Comment: you need to comma separate all the names, to a comma separated list as mentioned above... How you do that depends on how you are calling the query

Comment: Can't get it to work, can you try to form a query like I putted in my question (bottom)? Thanks for your time btw!